# Google Spreadsheet API issue

Tags: php, api, google-sheets

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 
{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", 
"errors": [ { "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "domain": "global", 
"reason": "forbidden" } ], 
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } 
}
```

My code is:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('google-api-php-client-2.1.1/client_s‌​ecret.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$spreadsheetId = '1Ybwc_wNhvc6tVQIRY-33qwkY0WoGj09uIQ3YQqa9fvo';
$range = 'sample!A2:E'; $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
if (count($values) == 0) {
    print "No data found.\n";
} else {
    print "Name, Major:\n";
    foreach ($values as $row) {
          printf("%s, %s\n", $row[0], $row[4]);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help/guide me in find the cause of the issue?

Comment: Post code that you have tried !

Comment: The message is telling you what is wrong: `The request is missing a valid API key`.

Comment: CODE:

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('google-api-php-client-2.1.1/client_secret.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

$spreadsheetId = '1Ybwc_wNhvc6tVQIRY-33qwkY0WoGj09uIQ3YQqa9fvo';
$range = 'sample!A2:E';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
if (count($values) == 0) {
  print "No data found.\n";
} else {
  print "Name, Major:\n";
  foreach ($values as $row) { printf("%s, %s\n", $row[0], $row[4]);
  }
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this is for the php client library, see 
[Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app) for information regarding enabling the API and getting Credentials for your code.  From that page note:

1. To use OAuth 2.0 in a web application, first create web application credentials for your project in the API Console.
2. All web applications that use OAuth 2.0 must have credentials that identify the application to the OAuth 2.0 server. Applications that have these credentials can access the APIs that you enabled for your project

The information on the above linked page will guide you in getting a valid API key.

Comment: I have one more doubt,
In the  'OAuth consent screen' tab there is currently only one email address assigned, so the API works for this email perfect (means i can fetch the spread sheet data, can update the content using API). So if i assign a group instead single email, will the API work for all emails in the group assigned same as single email?

Comment: I cannot answer that and would suggest you post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you update application scopes later you have to re-authenticate and update credentials.json.